# Spring SAML + Wildfly 8 + IBM Jdk (1.7) - java.lang.RuntimeException: org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: [ERR 0462] An unsupported encoding is encountered

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am getting a error when deploying spring-saml application in Wildfly 8 with IBM JDK 1.7. Interestingly Googling got me no answers.

The error stacktrace is

```
Caused by: org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: [ERR 0462] An unsupported encoding is encountered.
at org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl.write(Unknown Source) [xml.jar:]
at org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLHelper.writeNode(XMLHelper.java:892)
at org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLHelper.writeNode(XMLHelper.java:872)
at org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLHelper.nodeToString(XMLHelper.java:834)
at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:159)
at org.opensaml.xml.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:143)
at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:203)
at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.initializeXMLTooling(DefaultBootstrap.java:186)
at org.opensaml.DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap(DefaultBootstrap.java:92)
at org.opensaml.PaosBootstrap.bootstrap(PaosBootstrap.java:27)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap.postProcessBeanFactory(SAMLBootstrap.java:42)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:194)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the dependency between **opensaml.jar** and **serializer.jar**.
As you used **Spring Security SAML plugin**, you may be using the following libraries (as they are in the demo application):

- opensaml-2.6.1.jar
- spring-security-config-3.1.2.jar
- spring-security-core-3.2.1.jar
- spring-security-web-3.2.1.jar
- spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.jar

**Wildfly 8** (and **9** too) both are packed with **serializer-2.7.1.jbossorg-1.jar** (**/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/xalan/main**) which seems to have some differences with the "standard" **serializer-2.7.1.jar** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/serializer/2.7.1).

I compared both jars and they contain the same classes and resources, however their sizes differ. The "standard" one was compiled with IBM JDK 1.3.1, JBoss version with Oracle JDK 1.6_20 - This is based on both MANIFEST.MF files.
Note opensaml.jar was compiled with the "standard" serializer library based on the Maven repository information.

I was searching for the source code of the "standard" **serializer-2.7.1.jar** but I could not find it. However, I found another 2.7.1 build, this time from Spring and compared with the one JBoss source, and they have some differences. I assume that if I compare the "standard" source code I will find the same. It is not a simple file renaming as I have seen before.

The next thing I did was a little bit of experimentation. 
Firstly just dropped **serializer-2.7.1.jar** into my **application.war/WEB-INF/lib**, started **Wildfly (v 8.2.1)** and the application started without any issues. Removed the JAR and back to the exception.

Next, I changed **WF’s xalan module** to use **serializer-2.7.1.jar** instead **serializer-2.7.1.jbossorg-1.jar** (removed the jar file and edited module.xml). Started WF, and surprise, I got the same exception. I even tried changing to **serializer-2.7.1.jbossorg-2.jar** (packed with **Wildfly 10**) and **serializer-2.7.2.jar** (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/serializer/2.7.2) and the exception still occurred.

Finally, I rolled back the module changes to the original state and created a **custom WF module including serializer-2.7.1.jar** and added the module dependency in the application “**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**”.

It is important to highlight the application starts without any issue (or additional serializer.jar) under **WAS 8.5.5** and **WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5**. (target production AS and another development AS respectively). Custom modules in Wildfly are handy to avoid modifying the application WAR on this kind of scenarios.

As an additional note, as part of my test to solve this issue I upgraded to the latest **Spring-Security (3.2.9)** and **Open-SAML (2.6.4)** and I needed to upgrade to **serialize.jar to 2.7.2**.

*P.S. I worked with Mahe in the same project, but he left few months ago and I got the task to work out this issue.*